# How to get only the strings that are >4 in a data frame

Tags: python

I have this script that reads an Excel file which contains a bunch of quotes in each line, and then I set and filter by keyword. I need to filter by the word length of the strings, e.g. the length of 'one dog' is 2. I want to select the data frame to point me only to the strings that are > 3 words long, like 'i have a dog.'

```
keywords = ['dogs']

solution_category = [] 

# Lower keyword.
keywords_lower = [x.lower() for x in keywords]


if not solution_category:
    print("Words:", keywords_lower)

    # Search for occurence of keyword.
    df_data_clean = df[(df['Conversa'].str.lower()).str.contains('|'.join(keywords_lower))]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, [`pandas.Series.str.len`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) could be used instead of a custom function.

```py
# Search for occurency of keyword.
df_data_clean = df[(df['Conversa'].str.contains('|'.join(keywords_lower), case=False)]

# Filter data where column `Conversa` has > 3 words
df_data_clean = df_data_clean.loc[df_data_clean['Conversa'].str.split(' ').str.len() > 3]
```

Comment: It turned out great!

Answer (score 0):

You could define the following function which (naively) counts the number of words in a given string:

```
def word_count(string):
    # removes leading/trailing whitespace, partitions string
    # by whitespace and counts the number of elements in partition 
    return len(string.strip().split())
```

Here are some examples.

```
example1 = "I have a dog."
print(word_count(example1) > 3)
# True

example2 = "My dog."
print(word_count(example2) > 3)
# False
```

You can then filter using this function.

Answer (score 0):

An intuitive way would be to create your own function which splits the string in spaces and takes the length of the resulting array:

```py
def get_num_words(string):
    words = string.strip().split(' ')
    num_words = len(words)

    return num_words
```

Next apply this to your DataFrame along with your specified condition:

```
filtered = df[df.apply(get_num_words) > 3]
```

Edit: As the other answer demonstrated, string.strip() should also be used to avoid overcounting.